# Fetch data directly from firebase realtime database and not from local storage?

Tags: firebase, flutter, firebase-realtime-database, dart

I am using flutter and firebase realtime database . I want one information to be fetched directly from database and not from the local storage . How can I prevent that?
The code that I am using

```
static Stream<Event> getUserPresence(String uid) =>
      FirebaseDatabase.instance.reference().child('/status/$uid').onValue;
```

Comment: Wats wrong with ur code

Comment: I think the answer on this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55436007/flutter-firestore-take-long-retrieving-data-while-offline) will help you!